# References Assembly EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I'm working on one of those new "Class Library (NuGet Package)" projects in Visual Studio. Everything was going fine until the other day it started raising an error about a:'assembly 'EntityFramework.Core, Version=7.0.0.0 [reference?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSF5W.png)?

How can I install the 7.0 version of EntityFramework into my Nuget packages??

Comment: The bigger issue is that you probably need to learn more about ET before you use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This issue" says that you need to add a reference to:

> assembly 'EntityFramework.Core, Version=7.0.0.0

You can solve it by running the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework.Core -Pre
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0012 The type 'IUserTwoFactorStore<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. CMS2 C:\Users\Familia Herrera\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\code\CMS2\CMS2\App_Start\AuthDbConfig.cs 17 Active

Comment: For that you need Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core . Look at the error message, it is quite suggestive. Then if it says you must add reference to... you can search that package [on nuget](https://www.nuget.org).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the EF version is different and following 2 assemblies are not supported.

```
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

Comment the above 2 lines and the following line in the code behind of your `.edmx`

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```